# Clojure filter by id the nested map in a vector

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In the vector and map data example:

```
        [{:id 2, 
        :codigo "2", 
        :subcats 
            [{:id 3, 
              :codigo "3", 
              :subcats [], 
              :slug "pens-ss", 
              :foto nil, 
              :parent 2}
             {:id 4, 
              :codigo "44", 
              :subcats [], 
              :slug "rotula", 
              :foto nil, 
              :parent 2}
             {:id 5, 
              :codigo "hand", 
              :subcats 
                  [{:id 6, 
                      :codigo "caba", 
                      :subcats [], 
                      :slug "caballetes",
                      :foto nil, 
                      :parent 5}
                   {:id 7, 
                      :codigo "Carton", 
                      :subcats 
                           [{:id 9, 
                             :codigo "ooo", 
                             :subcats [], 
                             :slug "carton-piedra-el-nuevo", 
                             :parent 7}], 
                      :slug "cartoncillos", 
                      :foto nil, 
                      :parent 5}],
               :slug "hands", 
               :foto nil, 
               :padre 2}], 
        :slug "paper",
        :foto nil, 
        :padre nil}]
```

I can filter the first level of id, but can't filter the nested "subcats" by id. How to filter the nested map inside a vector without "for"?. I need get the nesteds map, example, id = 5 return all subcats:

```
(filter #(= (:id %) 5 ) @cats)
```

Finding by id 5, I want to return this:

```
             {:id 5, 
              :codigo "hand", 
              :subcats 
                  [{:id 6, 
                      :codigo "caba", 
                      :subcats [], 
                      :slug "caballetes",
                      :foto nil, 
                      :parent 5}
                   {:id 7, 
                      :codigo "Carton", 
                      :subcats 
                           [{:id 9, 
                             :codigo "ooo", 
                             :subcats [], 
                             :slug "carton-piedra-el-nuevo", 
                             :parent 7}], 
                      :slug "cartoncillos", 
                      :foto nil, 
                      :parent 5}],
               :slug "hands", 
               :foto nil, 
               :padre 2}
```

Comment: roughly `(filter (fn [{:keys [subcats]}] (some #(= (:id %) 5 ) subcats)) @cats)`

Comment: Can you give an example of query and result that you want to achieve? Do you want to filter nested subcats by path of ids?

Comment: @cfrick Now, the first level does not find it, the data example: id = 2

Comment: @chivam for example from :id 5, I need all your subcats. This give the first level :id 2 (filter #(= (:id %) 5 ) @cats)

Comment: I understood the question as "give me all "root cats", that contain a subcat with id N"; I'd like to second, that you should give a (simplifie) example of input and output expected.

Comment: @cfrick For example: filter :id 5 and get ids 6,7 and 9. Another filtering by :id 4, only get id 4 because haven't subcats

Comment: I'd use tree-seq then or rather use treeseq to build a map from id to node.

Comment: @cfrick some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a root node of

```
(def root {:id 2, 
        :codigo "2", 
        :subcats 
            [{:id 3, 
              :codigo "3", 
              :subcats [], 
              :slug "pens-ss", 
              :foto nil, 
              :parent 2}
             {:id 4, 
              :codigo "44", 
              :subcats [], 
              :slug "rotula", 
              :foto nil, 
              :parent 2}
             {:id 5, 
              :codigo "hand", 
              :subcats 
                  [{:id 6, 
                      :codigo "caba", 
                      :subcats [], 
                      :slug "caballetes",
                      :foto nil, 
                      :parent 5}
                   {:id 7, 
                      :codigo "Carton", 
                      :subcats 
                           [{:id 9, 
                             :codigo "ooo", 
                             :subcats [], 
                             :slug "carton-piedra-el-nuevo", 
                             :parent 7}], 
                      :slug "cartoncillos", 
                      :foto nil, 
                      :parent 5}],
               :slug "hands", 
               :foto nil, 
               :padre 2}], 
        :slug "paper",
        :foto nil, 
        :padre nil})
```

you can get a sequence of all the nodes using `tree-seq`:

```
(tree-seq map? :subcats root)
```

then you can find the node you need by `:id`:

```
(first (filter #(= 5 (:id %)) (tree-seq map? :subcats root)))
```

If the data returned is a sequence at the top level, you can use `mapcat` to retrieve all the nodes in the forest:

```
(def root [{:id 2, ...}])

(mapcat #(tree-seq map? :subcats %) root)
```

Comment: when the data is a vector can I change to map with this: (into {} data)?, but only convert the last line of data. Any suggestion?

Comment: You should update your question, with an example of the desired output.

Comment: @AlanThompson The API response with [{...}], and the tree-seq start with a map not with a vector

Comment: @dpmontero - I've updated the answer, does that work for you?